# How can I know external HDD used time?

Tags: external-disk

I want to know how long I used my external HDD. The HDD is WD My Book model. How can I know that?

Comment: are you asking how old the unit is (for warranty purposes maybe) or are you trying to find out how much usage your drive has had?

Comment: And exactly is "usage"? Time powered up, time of all read/writes?

Comment: @StuWilson Latter one. I wanna know how long the drive being used.

Answer (score 1):

If your disk supports S.M.A.R.T. feature then you can learn it from Disk Utility through clicking to info button after selecting related disk from the disk list.